# Static / Dynamic source code analysis

Tags: c, security, web-applications

I took a class named "Secure Code", and in our next assignment we are supposed to do static / dynamic analysis of some C files and of a JavaEE Web Project.

I checked out "Source Monitor" and ran it on the C files, but (unless I didn't get how to use it!) it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Considering the topic, I'd be interested in knowing if there are tools for detecting "insecure" code, i.e. code that is potentially attackable through buffer overflows, SQL-Injections, XSS ... So I'd like it to point out which functions should be "upgraded" (e.g. fgets instead of gets, or a PreparedStatement instead of a normal SQL statement)

Note: I'd prefer open source softwares, possibly for Windows (I have Ubuntu on a VM but I am not really good with it... I generally spend more time finding out how to configure the tools than running them).

Thank you for your tips!

Comment: [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) does this for Rails apps, but some of the warning types are fairly general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frama-C's value analysis](http://frama-c.com/value.html) is open-source, [available pre-compiled for Windows](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2012-February/003040.html), and was used to find such security bugs as [this one in the QuickLZ C library](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/04/05/QuickLZ-1) or [this one in Polar SSL](http://polarssl.org/trac/changeset/1221/trunk).

This said, you may find that it is a lot to get used to for just a school assignment, and then again, are you actually expected to find security bugs in a school assignment?

Comment: thank you I will have a look at it. Maybe the right word was "lecture" and not "class", since it's at the University. We already worked with those problems and we had to find several exploits on the files. So I guess that the goal now is to confirm our previous findings.

Comment: so, it is indeed a pain in the a** to configure it on Windows. I just spent like two hours trying to load a source file on the GUI, but it alway says "Frama-C aborted because of invalid user input. Look at the console for additional information (if any)."... and of course the console is empty!

Comment: I also tried it on Linux, there at least I got an output, but I didn't quite understand it. It is a serie of "weird statements" ended by the warnings, which are like "[kernel] warning: No code for function fprintf, default assigns". The interesting point is that the biggest flaw of the code came from a gets (it was prone to a buffer overflow), but frama-c doesn't give any warning on it. any ideas?

Comment: According to the manual page on my system, all `gets()` calls should be considered unsecure, so you could just use the command `grep [^f]gets *.c`. Frama-C's value analysis, that you apparently were able to launch (yes, it is verbose, but not every message is a warning), finds buffer overflows and other exploitable C undefined behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

For the *JavaEE Web Project* use Persistence API, and you can use non-SQL statements, where hacking is theoretically impossible! The best  open source one is the [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). It's easy to use and very flexible.

Comment: Thank vut I don't think this solves my problem. I don't need to program anything, just to do testing.